# SSDT vs VS2015 Database Projects

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2014, sql-server-data-tools

Out of scope: Azure Database Development.

I am trying to decide between Visual Studio 2015 Database projects and SSDT.

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Database projects to develop and source control my SQL 2014 database application.

I understand that SSDT also provides a comprehensive and rich set of SQL database development features.

Which one of the VS15 DB Projects or SSDT are more powerful to developer SQL 2014 application.

I wish there was a comparison table that compares the two tools.

**Conclusion**

Based on the answers I understand that the two are very similar. Before this post, I was confused and I though they have a different set of capabilities, which is not correct.

Comment: I don't understand this question. In Visual Studio 2010, "database projects" and SSDT were different. Starting with Visual Studio 2012 and continuing through the most recent release of Visual Studio vNext Preview, they are the same thing.

Comment: @StevenGreen, I did not know that they are the same. This is a big news for more. I always though SSDT provides more features than VS Data Projects. Do you know any reference or article that confirms this?

Comment: I second Steven's comment. They are the same thing. You can use SSDT without Visual Studio (sort of), it just runs in the VS Shell. But it is all the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSDT database projects and VS2015 database projects are the same. "SSDT" used by itself refers to *all* the SQL Server features and tooling in Visual Studio, database projects included.

It would be great if you could also describe what problem you're hoping to solve by asking this question.

Answer (score 1):

The two are not mutually exclusive, so you could always try SSDT and see if there are features you value and if they fit into your workflow?

I am working with SQL Server every day, and have SSDT installed (I also have the SSDT-BI tools installed as I often use SSIS).  In my experience the standard SSDT tools are a poor man's SSMS, so I tend to do the majority of my database dev work in SSMS, syncing updates with a database project for version control and deployment script generation.

Comment: "The two are not mutually exclusive" means they are the same?

Comment: @AllanXu - SSDT database projects and VS2015 database projects are the _same_. "SSDT" used by itself refers to all the SQL Server tooling in Visual Studio, database projects included.

Comment: @DavidAtkinson, please post your answer so that I can mark it as the answer.

Comment: Done! I've also added a question for you, as it would be helpful in providing a full answer to find out what you're hoping to solve.